# How to create a time based trigger for a google spread sheet created with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I wonder if there is a way to create a time based trigger fir a google spread sheet created with google apps script.I googled a lot and no luck.what i am exactly looking for is,i created a google spread sheet and took the id of that spread sheet like this

```
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('Google Contacts');
    var id = spreadSheet.getId();
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('ssId', id);
```

and then i was trying to create a trigger for this spread sheet like this

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myTrigger").timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();
```

and myTrigger is this

```
    function myTrigger(e) {
    var range = e.range;
    range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

I want to run this trigger ,ie,this time based trigger on my spread sheet created with the previous method.And now i don't find a way for this.
What i am looking for is, i want to run this time based trigger on the spread sheet with this id 
`var id = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('ssId');`
I was able to create this trigger for this spread sheet with the code `ScriptApp.newTrigger('myTrigger').forSpreadsheet(id).onEdit().create();` but this is not triggering on a time based ,rather than it is triigering on editof the above spread sheet.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is your trigger function myTrigger is coded to expect an onEdit event rather than an time based trigger event, as a result the script simply crashes when your time-based trigger calls it.

You can probably see details of this failure in the Execution Transcript of your Script Editor.

The reason is the reference to `e.range`, with an OnEdit trigger e.range is the edited range, but on a time-based trigger e.range is undefined. This is because the time-based trigger has nothing to do with any given range of cells.

Since your goal seems to be to set a note saying when a given range was last modified, I don't think you can easily achieve your final goal with a time-based trigger, why not simply use the onEdit trigger?

If you want to interact with the spreadsheet from your time based trigger, you will need to open the spreadsheet and get the range, then take your actions.

```
function myTrigger(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var range = ss.getRange("A1:B1");
    range.setNote('...')
```

You can see the different properties of event vs time-driven triggers listed in the tables here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events

Comment: I had done this way.Thanks a lot.I was getting the id of the spread sheet from the time based trigger and then execute the functon on that spread sheet.So the problem get solved.